# Face cards or better?

Tags: savage-worlds, playing-cards

In the Savage Worlds RPG I have seen the phase "Face cards or better".

Does this mean Joker and or Aces as well as Jack, Queen and King?

Is this defined anywhere in the rule book?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

"Faces or better" is standard for any card which ranks above a 10. Given that SW uses ace high, and jokers are wild in the editions I've read, it's a given that aces and jokers beat a 10...

Explorer edition notes the countdown runs Ace to Deuce on page 60.

Comment: Exactly.  Only J/K/Q are "face cards," but joker and ace are "better" in SW.

Comment: I believe the Adventure Deck mentions face cards (when drawing a relic), and then specifically includes Aces/Jokers.  Don't have the reference handy though..